# SharePoint File.CopyTo removes version history

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

I am copying a file to SharePoint library from different library using File.CopyToUsingPath function.

I am setting overwrite parameter to True since many a times the file with same name would be present already.

> sourceFile.CopyToUsingPath(filePath, true);

I see that if file exists already, then version history is not maintained. I checked the same behavior from browser by using Copy To option from file menu. Version history is removed in both these cases.

I am using File.CopyTo function so that it is easy to copy larger files using this function. Is there any alternate function or I will have to copy the file using below Files.Add way.

> Folder.Files.AddUsingPath(path, fileAddParameters, fileStream);

Any pointers will be helpful. Thank you!